# Spring STS jpa + security + web

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

I started Spring starter project with option jpa,security,mysql,web

and I added application.properties **this code**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://kimdg3550.cafe24.com/kimdg3550
spring.datasource.username=kimdg3550
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and if I go to URL http://localhost:8080

**I get this message in mac**

"이 페이지를 보려면, localhost:8080에 있는 ‘Spring’ 영역에 로그인해야 합니다."

**이름 :**

**암호 :**

this message is korean and means

**"to look this page, you need to login 'Spring' in localhost:8080"**

**ID:**

**password:**

and like next image, I get 401 error

[401 error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FKrt.png)

If i need URL '/', I think 404, but I get 401 error

how can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Spring security in your build file, i.e in your pom.xml because Spring Boot auto configurs Spring security.

**You should either Remove Spring Security artifact in your pom.xml**

or **You should implement Spring security login (at least in memory authentication)**

Comment: @김명준 If it helps you, mark this as answer by clicking right mark beside the answer so that it will be helpful for others